# toString() method using generics

Tags: java, generics

I am new to using generics. I want to print out a pair of Integers and Strings. Here is my code:

```
public class Pair<T> {

private T first;
private T second;

public Pair(T first, T second) {
    this.first = first;
    this.second = second;
}

public T getFirst() {
    return first;
}

public T getSecond() {
    return second;
}

public void setFirst(T first) {
    this.first = first;
}

public void setSecond(T second) {
    this.second = second;
}
public <T> void toString(Pair<T> k) {
System.out.println(k.getFirst());
System.out.println(k.getSecond());
}



}


public class TestPair {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pair<String> pS = new Pair<String>("yay", "it worked" );
    Pair<Integer> pI = new Pair<Integer>(1, 2);
    pS.toString();
    pI.toString();

}

}
```

At the moment, it compiles but upon running TestPair class, I don't get anything printed out.

Comment: You have not overridden `toString()`, you have added an overload that takes a single argument (and is never called). Also, it is bad form to print to the console in a toString method. Print the return value of toString instead.

Comment: You are calling Object.toString() instead of your implementation. Your one takes a pair as argument.

Comment: Wow, that is an embarrassing mistake. Well you live and you learn. Thanks for the help guys. Also, @TypeIA, since I am using a return value, would I change the method name to public <T> T toString(Pair<T> k)?

Comment: @user3274 if you think about it I think you'll agree that the return type of `toString()` should be... `String` right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be aware that now, your `toString()` method doesn't override `Object.toString()` method (as it is stated in official Java tutorial [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html): *The overriding method has the same name, number and type of parameters, and return type as the method that it overrides*). . If you want to call you implementation of `toString()` you need to pass argument of type `Pair` to it, as your `toString()` requires `Pair` instance as an argument. I rather suggest you to change your `toString` method to:

```
public void toString() {
    System.out.println(this.getFirst());
    System.out.println(this.getSecond());
}
```

In that case when you call:

```
pS.toString();
pI.toString();
```

, you get correct results as now your `toString()` doesn't require `Pair` argument.

Comment: And when calling that new method would I do pS.toString() with that implementation or would it still be pS.toString(pS)?

Comment: @user3274 First option. Look:
public void toString() {...} - you don't have any argument in parenthesis right after words "toString", so you can't pass any argument if you want to call that method.

Answer (score 1):

The way you have it now, your "toString" takes a parameter so you have to pass it like so (note the parameters added to toString).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pair<String> pS = new Pair<String>("yay", "it worked");
    Pair<Integer> pI = new Pair<Integer>(1, 2);
    pS.toString(pS);
    pI.toString(pI);
}
```

Without the parameters - it calls the default toString() method of the object which returns a string representation like "test.Pair@33909752" which the class name followed by "@" followed by the address/pointer to the class. But since you are not printing the returned value from the default toString method of Object class - nothing prints.

The way toString typically should be coded is to return a String (you would override the toString method of the object). Something like:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Pair [first=" + first + ", second=" + second + "]";
}
```

Then in your main program you should print it like:

```
    System.out.println (pS.toString());
    System.out.println (pI.toString());
```

or simply (because when printing "toString()" is implied)

```
    System.out.println (pS);
    System.out.println (pI);
```

Comment: As above, would public String toString() method work for Integers i.e. in pI, I want the method to be for generic Types.

Comment: It will work for all types - since all types will have a toString() method (inherited from the parent of all classes - Object). When you say first=" + first, it really means first=" + String.valueOf(first) - so it will work for ALL types.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your code:

- In your main method you are calling `toString()` (with zero arguments) which the Pair class inherits from `Object`. This method returns a generic string like `Pair@123`. But as you don't do anything with this string, you don't get an output. You could create an output by writing `System.out.println(pS.toString());` (or even `System.out.println(pS);`.
- In your Pair-class, you have defined a toString method with one parameter. I suppose you wanted to overwrite the `Object.toString()`, so you should also use code like `public String toString() {return first.toString() + " " + second.toString()}` (plus null checks)

Comment: Considering I would want to keep the method of generic Type wouldn't it be wrong to create the toString() method with String as the type as it wouldn't then work with Integer?

Comment: [toString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) should always return a string.